# In "A Clockwork Orange," where was Alex's trial?

Tags: a-clockwork-orange

In ***A Clockwork Orange***, filmed in 1971 in Britain, a run-down youth **Alex DeLarge** commits murder in a mansion out in the forest somewhere. His friend betrays him and smashes him in the face, leaving him on the scene for the police come arrest him and interrogate. In the next scene, Alex is immediately taken to prison and sentenced to serve 14 years.

My question is *where was Alex's trial in this movie*? As they're in the car driving to the aforementioned crime-scene, we learn from Alex that the movie is supposedly set in 1995—*but wouldn't there still be trials?* They just can't automatically sentence someone the same day; it takes months to sentence a person to that kind of a prison term. Why wasn't there a trial?

Comment: I've always thought that this is one of the few occasions where you need to read the book to fully understand the film.. though you also need to see the film to fully understand the book. You've got to viddy to kopat, that's my soviet, my old droogs ;) [You also need one finger in the glossary, right the way through]

Comment: The point about 1995 is completely irrelevant.  The book presents what is known as a [dystopian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dystopian_literature) future (i.e. it's a speculation--no one in 1962 when the book was published, or in 1971 when the film was made, had any idea what 1995 would be like in reality.)

Answer (score 3):

The trial is not shown but is mentioned in this voiceover from Alex:

> This is the real weepy and like tragic part of the story beginning, oh
>   my brothers and only friends. **After a trial with judges and a jury,
>   and some very hard words spoken against your friend and humble
>   narrator, he was sentenced to 14 years in Staja No. 84F** among smelly
>   perverts and hardened prestoopnicks, the shock sending my dadda
>   beating his bruised and kroovy rookas against unfair Bog in his
>   Heaven, and my mom, boohoohooing in her mother's grief as her only
>   child and son of her bosom, like letting everybody down real
>   horrorshow.

Due to his lengthy record of offenses as a juvenile, Alex had been warned, earlier in the film, that he'd be going to prison for his next offense. [Probation officer P.R. Deltoid visits Alex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsrvURzZmDM) and says "next time it's not going to be the corrective school anymore... next time it's going to be *the bar-ly place [prison]* and all my work ruined." Deltoid also uses the term "*the stripey hole*" as another slang term for prison.

Answer (score 2):

The film is set in "A futuristic London", though I don't recall "1995" being uttered in the film I'll take your word for it.  The book was written in 1962 and the film was released in 1971, so in either instance 1995 would be considerably in the future.  The trial was not the focal point of the film or book, it was more about the psychology of violence.  As such, it's probable that you're supposed to infer that in the future, there are no trials.  Just sentences handed down by Magistrates.

Comment: Alex refers to the car they steal as a "Durango '95"... but that could be 2095, 2195, et cetera. Or could even be part of the model name.